# Simple java regular expression replace question

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple xml file and I want to remove everything before the first `<item>` tag.

```
<sometag>
  <something>
   .....
  </something>
  <item>item1
  </item>
  ....
</sometag>
```

The following java code is not working:

```
String cleanxml = rawxml.replace("^[\\s\\S]+<item>", "");
```

What is the correct way to do this? And how do I address the non-greedy issue? Sorry I'm a C# programmer.

Comment: Short answer: don't. Even Jon Skeet cannot parse XML using regular expressions. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you want to use regex, then you can use `replaceAll`. This solution uses a reluctant quantifier and a backreference:

```
String cleanxml = rawxml.replaceAll(".*?(<item>.*)", "$1");
```

Alternately you can use `replaceFirst`. This solution uses a positive lookahead.

```
String cleanxml = rawxml.replaceFirst(".*?(?=<item>)", "");
```

It makes more sense to just use `indexOf` and `substring`, though.

```
String cleanxml = rawxml.substring(rawxml.indexOf("<item>"));
```

---

The reason why `replace` doesn't work is that neither `char` nor `CharSequence` overloads is regex-based. It's simple character (sequence) replacement.

---

Also, as others are warning you, unless you're doing processing of simple XMLs, you shouldn't use regex. You should use an actual XML parser instead.

Answer (score 3):

> ... What is the correct way to do
>   this? ...

Since you asked about the correct way the correct way to do this is to parse the XML and remove the nodes and re-serialize to a String. You should never use regular expressions for manipulating XML or any other structured document that has parsers available ( JSON, YAML, etc).
For small XML I would suggest [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/).

Answer (score 1):

use

```
replaceAll
```

or

```
replaceFirst
```

just replace will look for string matches
HTH

Comment: replace() does not accept a regular expression. It interprets its arguments as literal strings.